# Lexical error on line 1: unrecognized text. erroneous area: 1: l + l * 0.2 ^..^

Tags: reactjs

After installing node modules, while executing command 'npm run build' facing issue lexical error on line 1: unrecognized text. erroneous area: 1: l + l * 0.2 ^..^
But text 'l + l * 0.2 ^..^' not found in my source code any idea ?
Currently using node 14 version

Comment: although question has very less context, what i generally do is, I uninstall everything and try to install one by one and then see when this error starts to show up so that I can narrow down where this error is happening

Comment: I am getting same error in github actions. Not sure how to trace this, since I could not find this code from my file. May be due to upgrade of nodejs to 16 and possibly code from dependency. Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: @Meenu Is this error resolved?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this was the problem with you. There was bug from rsuite npm package, I raised issue and they have resolved now. Finally, I am using latest version of rsuite.

https://github.com/rsuite/rsuite/issues/3473